# Calculate score based on responses to multiple-responses questions

Tags: r

I have user data from between 1 and 20 multiple-response questions. In other words, users did not all answer the same number of questions; they could choose how many of the 20 questions they wanted to answer. All questions have the same number of response options (which was 44), and users could choose as few or as many response options as they wanted for each question.

To give an example, here's a subset of the data (representing 3 multiple-response questions with 5 response options on each):

```
mydata <- structure(list(id = 1:5, q1.response1 = c(1L, NA, 1L, NA, 1L), 
q1.response2 = c(NA, 1L, 1L, NA, NA), q1.response3 = c(NA, 
1L, 1L, 1L, NA), q1.response4 = c(1L, 1L, 1L, NA, 1L), q1.response5 = c(NA, 
1L, 1L, NA, NA), q2.response1 = c(NA, 1L, NA, NA, NA), q2.response2 = c(1L, 
NA, 1L, 1L, 1L), q2.response3 = c(NA, 1L, NA, 1L, NA), q2.response4 = c(1L, 
NA, NA, NA, 1L), q2.response5 = c(NA, 1L, NA, 1L, NA), q3.response1 = c(1L, 
1L, NA, 1L, NA), q3.response2 = c(NA, 1L, NA, NA, NA), q3.response3 = c(1L, 
NA, NA, 1L, NA), q3.response4 = c(1L, 1L, NA, NA, NA), q3.response5 = c(1L, 
NA, NA, NA, NA)), .Names = c("id", "q1.response1", "q1.response2", 
"q1.response3", "q1.response4", "q1.response5", "q2.response1", 
"q2.response2", "q2.response3", "q2.response4", "q2.response5", 
"q3.response1", "q3.response2", "q3.response3", "q3.response4", 
"q3.response5"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L))
```

A "1" indicates that they checked off that option; NA indicates that they did not.

What I was to do is calculate the following for each of the 5 users: [image: formula], where n<sub>i</sub> is the number of responses that appear in a particular combination of questions, and i = 1, ..., 2<sup>k</sup>, where k is the number of multiple-choice questions.

For example, if another person responds to 3 multiple-response questions (as in the above example), each of the 5 response options will fall into ONLY 1 of 2<sup>3</sup>=8 possible group combinations:
1) Response options selected only in question 1
2) Response options selected only in question 2
3) Response options selected only in question 3
4) Response options selected in both question 1 and 2
5) Response options selected in both question 1 and 3
6) Response options selected in both question 2 and 3
7) Response options selected in question 1, 2, and 3
8) Response options that were not selected at all

As an example, for respondent #1 in the sample data:
1) Response options selected only in question 1: none = 0 responses
2) Response options selected only in question 2: response2 = 1 response
3) Response options selected only in question 3: response3, response5 = 2 responses
4) Response options selected in both question 1 and 2: none = 0 responses
5) Response options selected in both question 1 and 3: response1 = 1 response
6) Response options selected in both question 2 and 3: none = 0 responses
7) Response options selected in question 1, 2, and 3: response4 = 1 response
8) Response options that were not selected at all: none = 0 responses

So the score for this respondent would be:
(0*log2(0))+(1*log2(1))+(2*log2(2))+(0*log2(0))+(1*log2(1))+(0*log2(0))+(1*log2(1))+(0*log2(0)) = 2

Any idea how to code this in R?

Comment: No effort, no answer.

Comment: My R skills are not good enough to do this in an efficient way. I've been trying to do this is in a piecemeal manner with for-loops and everything I've tried has turned into a convoluted mess, so none of my attempts seem worth posting because they are not a good starting point to build on.

Comment: I feel that you would have gotten a better response with no code but a concise and clear question.

Comment: I'd like to add my 2 cents here with respect to the quality of the question: I agree it's a demerit that there's no code given and that it may appear the OP is just asking us to do his work for him. But this is obviously a very complex problem, and IMO it's very well expressed; it's as clear as anyone could make it, given the complexity. It has a verbal description, mathematical notation, and an example provided for further clarity, listing every response case comprising a single evaluation of the formula. The OP clearly put a lot of effort into the question, which is worth a lot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first thing I would do here is transform your data into long format. There are various ways of doing this, such as the base R [`reshape()`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/reshape.html) function, and the [reshape2](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/reshape2/index.html) package, but I actually decided to do it manually in this case by constructing a new data.frame using the constructor function [`data.frame()`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/data.frame.html) and a few carefully written calls to [`rep()`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/rep.html). This approach also depends on flattening the original data.frame (minus the initial `id` column, which I instantiate separately) to a vector via [`as.matrix()`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/matrix.html) and then [`c()`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/c.html), which follows the original data *across rows* and then *across columns*. The `rep()` calls had to be designed to align with that order.

```
mydata;
##   id q1.response1 q1.response2 q1.response3 q1.response4 q1.response5 q2.response1 q2.response2 q2.response3 q2.response4 q2.response5 q3.response1 q3.response2 q3.response3 q3.response4 q3.response5
## 1  1            1           NA           NA            1           NA           NA            1           NA            1           NA            1           NA            1            1            1
## 2  2           NA            1            1            1            1            1           NA            1           NA            1            1            1           NA            1           NA
## 3  3            1            1            1            1            1           NA            1           NA           NA           NA           NA           NA           NA           NA           NA
## 4  4           NA           NA            1           NA           NA           NA            1            1           NA            1            1           NA            1           NA           NA
## 5  5            1           NA           NA            1           NA           NA            1           NA            1           NA           NA           NA           NA           NA           NA
NU <- nrow(mydata);
NQ <- 3;
NO <- 5;
long <- data.frame(id=rep(mydata$id,NQ*NO),question=rep(1:NQ,each=NO*NU),option=rep(1:NO,each=NU,NQ),response=c(as.matrix(mydata[-1])));
long;
##    id question option response
## 1   1        1      1        1
## 2   2        1      1       NA
## 3   3        1      1        1
## 4   4        1      1       NA
## 5   5        1      1        1
## 6   1        1      2       NA
## 7   2        1      2        1
## 8   3        1      2        1
## 9   4        1      2       NA
## 10  5        1      2       NA
## 11  1        1      3       NA
## 12  2        1      3        1
## 13  3        1      3        1
## 14  4        1      3        1
## 15  5        1      3       NA
## 16  1        1      4        1
## 17  2        1      4        1
## 18  3        1      4        1
## 19  4        1      4       NA
## 20  5        1      4        1
## 21  1        1      5       NA
## 22  2        1      5        1
## 23  3        1      5        1
## 24  4        1      5       NA
## 25  5        1      5       NA
## 26  1        2      1       NA
## 27  2        2      1        1
## 28  3        2      1       NA
## 29  4        2      1       NA
## 30  5        2      1       NA
## 31  1        2      2        1
## 32  2        2      2       NA
## 33  3        2      2        1
## 34  4        2      2        1
## 35  5        2      2        1
## 36  1        2      3       NA
## 37  2        2      3        1
## 38  3        2      3       NA
## 39  4        2      3        1
## 40  5        2      3       NA
## 41  1        2      4        1
## 42  2        2      4       NA
## 43  3        2      4       NA
## 44  4        2      4       NA
## 45  5        2      4        1
## 46  1        2      5       NA
## 47  2        2      5        1
## 48  3        2      5       NA
## 49  4        2      5        1
## 50  5        2      5       NA
## 51  1        3      1        1
## 52  2        3      1        1
## 53  3        3      1       NA
## 54  4        3      1        1
## 55  5        3      1       NA
## 56  1        3      2       NA
## 57  2        3      2        1
## 58  3        3      2       NA
## 59  4        3      2       NA
## 60  5        3      2       NA
## 61  1        3      3        1
## 62  2        3      3       NA
## 63  3        3      3       NA
## 64  4        3      3        1
## 65  5        3      3       NA
## 66  1        3      4        1
## 67  2        3      4        1
## 68  3        3      4       NA
## 69  4        3      4       NA
## 70  5        3      4       NA
## 71  1        3      5        1
## 72  2        3      5       NA
## 73  3        3      5       NA
## 74  4        3      5       NA
## 75  5        3      5       NA
```

Here's a demo of how to use `reshape()` to accomplish the same thing. As you can see, this requires two consecutive calls to `reshape()`, because we need to longify both the `option` variable and the `question` variable. The order of these two columns ends up being reversed from what I created above, but that's circumstantial. Note that this approach absolves us of the need to manually store (or derive, which could theoretically be done) `NQ` and `NO` in advance of the transformation, but at the expense of the complexity of appeasing the quirks of the `reshape()` function.

```
long1 <- transform(structure(reshape(mydata,dir='l',varying=2:ncol(mydata),timevar='option'),reshapeLong=NULL),option=as.integer(sub('^response','',option,perl=T)));
long2 <- transform(structure(reshape(long1,dir='l',idvar=c('id','option'),varying=3:ncol(long1),timevar='question',sep=''),reshapeLong=NULL),question=as.integer(question),response=q,q=NULL);
rownames(long2) <- NULL;
identical(long,long2[names(long)]);
## [1] TRUE
```

The next step is figuring out which options for each user fell into which category. By "category" I'm referring to the combination of questions for which that user selected that particular option. Your formula requires first summing up the number of options that fall into each category.

Initially, I got the idea to normalize each user's selections for a particular option to a single number by treating each question as a binary digit and summing up the place-value-weighted numerical value of each selection. So, for example, if a user selected a particular option on questions 1 and 3, but *not* on question 2, then that would be binary 101 which would normalize to 5. This was the result, using [`aggregate()`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/aggregate.html) to group by `id` and `option`:

```
combo <- aggregate(cbind(category=response)~id+option,long,function(x) sum(x*2^(length(x):1-1),na.rm=T),na.action=na.pass);
combo;
##    id option category
## 1   1      1        5
## 2   2      1        3
## 3   3      1        4
## 4   4      1        1
## 5   5      1        4
## 6   1      2        2
## 7   2      2        5
## 8   3      2        6
## 9   4      2        2
## 10  5      2        2
## 11  1      3        1
## 12  2      3        6
## 13  3      3        4
## 14  4      3        7
## 15  5      3        0
## 16  1      4        7
## 17  2      4        5
## 18  3      4        4
## 19  4      4        0
## 20  5      4        6
## 21  1      5        1
## 22  2      5        6
## 23  3      5        4
## 24  4      5        2
## 25  5      5        0
```

However, I then realized that this approach could easily lead to a problem. The issue is that it requires multiplying by place values that extend up to 2<sup>*k*-1</sup>. For your particular case *k* is 20, so that's only 524288, which is perfectly manageable, but imagine if you had 100 questions; the largest place value would be 633825300114114700748351602688! That doesn't fit into a 32-bit integer and so it would be converted to a double (roughly 6.33825300114115e+29), and that would screw up the entire aggregation we're going to have to do next (stay tuned), since nearby categories would be "rounded" together, due to the floating absolute precision of doubles.

I thought about how to solve this problem, and realized that it makes most sense to just switch to a string representation of the category. This will allow us to handle large numbers of questions, while still providing a simple and easily comparable representation of the category. I also manually set it as a factor rather than a character vector, which will be useful later on for the [`tabulate()`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/tabulate.html) call. So, here's the improved solution, again using `aggregate()` to group by `id` and `option`:

```
combo <- aggregate(cbind(category=response)~id+option,long,function(x) factor(paste(replace(x,is.na(x),0),collapse='')),na.action=na.pass);
combo;
##    id option category
## 1   1      1      101
## 2   2      1      011
## 3   3      1      100
## 4   4      1      001
## 5   5      1      100
## 6   1      2      010
## 7   2      2      101
## 8   3      2      110
## 9   4      2      010
## 10  5      2      010
## 11  1      3      001
## 12  2      3      110
## 13  3      3      100
## 14  4      3      111
## 15  5      3      000
## 16  1      4      111
## 17  2      4      101
## 18  3      4      100
## 19  4      4      000
## 20  5      4      110
## 21  1      5      001
## 22  2      5      110
## 23  3      5      100
## 24  4      5      010
## 25  5      5      000
```

As a slight alternative, to save on characters, we could use more compact encodings than the above binary strings. Here's a rather intricate line of code to build hex strings:

```
combo <- aggregate(cbind(category=response)~id+option,long,function(x) factor(paste(c(0:9,letters[1:6])[colSums(matrix(c(rep(0,ceiling(length(x)/4)*4-length(x)),x)*2^(3:0),4),na.rm=T)+1],collapse='')),na.action=na.pass);
combo;
##    id option category
## 1   1      1        5
## 2   2      1        3
## 3   3      1        4
## 4   4      1        1
## 5   5      1        4
## 6   1      2        2
## 7   2      2        5
## 8   3      2        6
## 9   4      2        2
## 10  5      2        2
## 11  1      3        1
## 12  2      3        6
## 13  3      3        4
## 14  4      3        7
## 15  5      3        0
## 16  1      4        7
## 17  2      4        5
## 18  3      4        4
## 19  4      4        0
## 20  5      4        6
## 21  1      5        1
## 22  2      5        6
## 23  3      5        4
## 24  4      5        2
## 25  5      5        0
```

Note how this result looks identical to the place value solution given earlier. That's just because this sample data has only 3 questions and thus only 8 categories, which doesn't extend into the hexadecimal letter range. On the other hand, the identicalness is a nice demonstration of how both solutions use a kind of numerical value representation, with the place value solution using actual integers, and this solution using hexadecimal strings.

The next step is to aggregate on the category, summing up ***n<sub>i</sub>* log<sub>2</sub> *n<sub>i</sub>*** for all categories.

Now, since the addend is zero for *n<sub>i</sub>* = 0, we don't actually have to add up the value for *every* possible category; we can ignore the ones that are not present. This is fortunate, since there are 2<sup>*k*</sup> categories, which would become huge for large *k*. In other words, all we have to do is sum up the expression for each category that is represented in the data to get the result. And furthermore, since the addend is also zero for *n<sub>i</sub>* = 1, since log<sub>2</sub>(1) = 0, we can excise every category that has less than 2 constituents. Thus we have:

```
res <- aggregate(cbind(score=category)~id,combo,function(x) { nc <- tabulate(x); nc <- nc[nc>1]; sum(nc*log2(nc)); });
res;
##   id score
## 1  1     2
## 2  2     4
## 3  3     8
## 4  4     2
## 5  5     2
```

This was a very complex question, and I might have made a mistake somewhere, so please check my work!

Comment: Thank you for the amazingly detailed answer! I went through each part both with the example data and my full dataset and found that your method does exactly what I was after, confirming the final scores for some of the respondents with manual calculations to be sure. Your level of detail and step-by-step approach is also greatly appreciated on its own merits: it allowed me to really understand what you did and to learn how I can apply this type of method to future problems on my own, which is great since, as I said in response to the above comment, I am still developing my R skills.